# Update to flight inspiration API: Is only the JSON response changing? Query unchanged?

Tags: amadeus

I got an email today about upcoming changes to the Flight Inspiration and Flight Destination searches. It [sounds as if the JSON response](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/flight-inspiration-api-update) will now be more granular with results showing specific airports. But I am unclear about whether I have to change my POST requests to use airport codes. Will requests continue to be city codes, or now only airport code requests, or are both acceptable? Again, from the linked blog post, it sounds as if only the response is changing, but API POST requests will remain the same, i.e., city codes. Can someone confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this new version, the Flight Inspiration Search and Flight Cheapest Date APIs will still accept city code as input but will return airport codes at the `destination` field rather than city codes. Thus you won't have to change anything in the query parameter of the APIs.

Comment: I am not asking about Flight Offers. I am asking about Flight Inspiration and Flight Destination searches.

Comment: Today the flight inspiration APIs take city code as input and return city codes. When the change happens, they will still take city code as input but will return airport codes. For your information, these APIs support GET methods and not POST as you mentioned in your question, that’s why I thought you were asking for the input of the POST Flight Offers Search.

Comment: Sorry about the GET/POST mix up on my part. I wrote this code quite a while ago and did not remember that detail of the API. I think you have answered my question, but... 
Just to be perfectly clear, will these endpoints continue to accept **only** city codes, or will they now accept both city codes **and** airport codes?

Comment: The endpoints will continue to accept city codes only.